# Excel - How can I sort by col A, and within that, Col B, and within that, Col C, e.t.c

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I'd like to know how I can sort  by col A, and within that, Col B,  and within that, Col C, e.t.c.

For example

Suppose I have this data

This is unsorted

```
2   1   4   3
1   3   3   2
5   1   1   4
5   4   2   5
1   2   5   5
4   3   3   1
3   2   5   4
1   5   1   5
4   4   1   2
1   4   4   1
5   3   2   4
3   5   1   3
2   4   3   3
1   2   3   1
5   1   5   1
```

I want to sort by col A,

So then   all the rows where col A have like values, will be bunched together.

For each of those bunches, I want to sort by Col B, and for each of those bunches i'd like to sort by Col C, giving an end result of

```
1   2   3   1
1   2   5   5
1   3   3   2
1   4   4   1
1   5   1   5
2   1   4   3
2   4   3   3
3   2   5   4
3   5   1   3
4   3   3   1
4   4   1   2
5   1   1   4
5   1   5   1
5   3   2   4
5   4   2   5
```

So, I haven't done anything with column D.

I can break that down if it's unclear, but i'll use a smaller example..

One can sort by col A,

Then space it out e.g.

```
1   3   3   2
1   2   5   5
1   5   1   5
1   4   4   1
1   2   3   1

2   1   4   3
2   4   3   3
```

then sort each chunk by col B  so the chunk where Col A contains 2s, in this case, is already sorted by Col B.  And we get

```
1   2   5   5
1   2   3   1
1   3   3   2
1   4   4   1
1   5   1   5

2   1   4   3
2   4   3   3
```

And then to sort by col C (each identical A,B), one could space it out

So we get

```
1   2   5   5
1   2   3   1

1   3   3   2

1   4   4   1

1   5   1   5

2   1   4   3

2   4   3   3
```

And we see there we have a lot of chunks of 1 row so nothing to sort.  We have one chunk of two rows and they are not ordered by col c yet, so they'll get reordered.

So

```
1   2   5   5
1   2   3   1
```

will become

```
1   2   3   1
1   2   5   5
```

The rest remain the same, and so we get

```
1   2   3   1               
1   2   5   5
1   3   3   2               
1   4   4   1               
1   5   1   5           
2   1   4   3               
2   4   3   3
```

Notice that it's sorted by Col A, Col B, Col C,   in the sense of, it's sorted by  Col A, and for each chunk that is like within Col A, it is sorted by col B, and for each chunk that is like with Col A and Col B, it is sorted by Col C.

I'd like to know if there is a rather automatic way to do that in excel, rather than rather manual process of sorting each chunk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In excel, choose data..sort

[image]

then choose "add level" and you can choose multiple columns

[image]

Apparently SQL can do it too, with a line along the lines of `SELECT ... ORDER BY col_a, col_b, col_c;`