# sort data by weekday

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, sorting

I want to analyze a large amount of data (2000>) with each singular data point corresponding to a weekday. What I want to do now is to sort my data by weekday while still having the data that is related to said date and weekday sorted accordingly so that each Monday keeps the data from it's related cell.

Example of block of data:

[image: Example of block of data]

Example of sorted block of data:

[image: Example of sorted block of data]

The first image is of the current format of the data and the second one is that of the ideal format of the data in order for me to analyze it.

Comment: Select all the data, then go to `Data -> Sort`. You can also read [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654) if you want more info or come back here if you are having a problem achieving the result you want

Comment: Sorry for taking some time to respond. Unfortunately this is not what I am asking for. I know how to sort a column or two, what I do not know is how to make it so that when I sort column A and B, for column C and D to follow along in the change. So if  cell A3 was sorted to A2, I would also want C3 to go to C2 and D3 to D2.

Comment: Then select columns A, B, C and D, not just A and B

Comment: Tried that already. Selecting the other columns and sorting does not work. Maybe because each cell is a result of an equation but still, selecting all columns and then sorting doesn't provide the needed result.

Comment: Ah!, that changes everything. Converting the formulas to their values is one option, for others, you'd need to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1365567/edit) and provide more info

Comment: Thank you so very much. Converting the formulas to their actual values instead of having the cells as results of formulas allowed the sorting to be done correctly along all the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming column A is you date and column B is your weekday.. I suggest to replace column B with the formula `=weekday(A1,3)` .

Then, convert to the formulas values to text.

Then sort it using the [dialog box](https://superuser.com/questions/1132689/excel-how-can-i-sort-by-col-a-and-within-that-col-b-and-within-that-col-c?rq=1) similar to the one mentioned by  @cybernetic.nomad

Sort by column B.. then column A.

Please share if it works(or doesn't..)  ( :

Comment: Thanks for the response however I still run into the original problem using this method. Yes, the date and the weekday do sort out well. The problem however is that the data that is related to the cells that do get sorted, don't follow along. So while I have the first two columns (date and weekday) sorted as I would need them to be, the other 2 are not as they are unaffected by sorting this way.

Comment: For more clarity, if in the sorting process A3 gets moved to A2, I would also need C3 and D3 to move to C2 and D2 respectively otherwise the sorting is useless.

Comment: you need to select column A + B + C + D before going into the sorting dialog box..

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was selecting all the columns before going to the dialog box however because column C+D were results of formulas they were not being sorted, changing them to their actual values as cybernetic.nomad suggested fixed this.

Comment: glad it solves. || I've updated my post. credit to @cybernetic.nomad  ( :

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]
**How it works:**

**I'm assuming that you have data in Range `A3:D17'.**

1. Write this Formula in Cell `B4' & fill down.

   ```
   =TEXT(WEEKDAY(A4,3),"DDDD")
   ```
2. Select Entire Data including Header row.
3. From `Home Tab` click `Sort & Filter` then hit 
   `Custom Sort`.
4. For `Column Sort By` select `Weekday`(Col 
   Header),`Values` for `Sort On` and `Custom` 
   for `Order`.
5. In `List Entries box` enter Weekdays list 
   `Monday to Sunday`.

***N.B.*** Check attached Screen Shot.

6. Click `Add` & finish with `Ok`.
7. Finally finish Sort process by  `Ok` button.

*You get the desire Data list.*